# How do I check if a session variable is set?

Tags: coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-10

I kept getting the "Error in custom script module" when checking if the session variable is set or not in my details page. Even if the session variable not set, wasn't this statement supposed to give me either true or false instead of error out?

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(session.mysiteShibboleth, "isAuthenticated") and (session.mysiteShibboleth.isAuthenticated) >
    <cflog text="Session-Defined-5: isAuthenticated" type="Information" file="Authentication">
<cfelse>
    <cflog text="Session-Defined-7: It's not authenticated'" type="Information" file="Authentication">
</cfif>
```

In my authenticate.cfm file, this is where the session variables are set.

```
<cfif cgiReferer eq shibboleth_url>
    <cfscript>
        session.mysiteShibboleth = StructNew();
        session.mysiteShibboleth.username=REReplace(http_header.headers.eppn, "@mysite.com","","ALL");
        session.mysiteShibboleth.mail=http_header.headers.eppn;
        session.mysiteShibboleth.groups=ArrayToList(REMatch('WEB\.[A-Z.-]+', http_header.headers.member));
        session.mysiteShibboleth.isAuthenticated="true";
    </cfscript>
</cfif>
```

I have also tried the following and it's still error out. I have read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771226/how-do-i-test-to-see-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-coldfusion-struct) and it doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

```
<cfif IsDefined("session.mysitecShibboleth.isAuthenticated")>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is it complaining about `session.mysiteShibboleth.isAuthenticated` or simply `session.mysiteShibboleth`? your first block of code assumes `session.mysiteShibboleth` exists, which might not be the case. YOu need to give us the *actual* error message with this sort of thing.

Comment: Do you have session management turned on in `application.cfc` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that `session.mysiteShibboleth` exists before you check for a key on `mysiteShibboleth`. That is likely the source of your problem, but if you gave us the actual error message received, we could help you better.

Also, note that `<cfif IsDefined("session.mysitecShibboleth.isAuthenticated")>` has an errant `c` in the variable name.

** Edit: Adding code example

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(session, "mysiteShibboleth">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(session.mysiteShibboleth, "isAuthenticated") and (session.mysiteShibboleth.isAuthenticated) >
    . . . 
    </cfif>
<cfelse>
    . . . 
</cfif>
```

Comment: I don't know if the session.mysiteShibboleth exists or not that is why I'm checking but checking error out.

Comment: The only error I see on the browser is that, "Error in custom script module." I'm not sure where else I can check for more info. on the error.

Comment: I looked in the CommonSpot log, it showed this exception: Exception: Element MYSITESHIBBOLETH.ISAUTHENTICATED is undefined in SESSION.

Comment: Even if that is true, wasn't the IsDefined("session.mysitecShibboleth.isAuthenticated") supposed to account for this error?

Comment: Can u check whether session management is true in your Application.CFC and session.mysitecShibbloeth is available in your season?

Comment: Also check cookie settings in your browser

Comment: No, I don't see any signs that our application.cfc uses session management.  And cookie is turned on my browser.

Comment: It error out on even this line: <cfif StructKeyExists(session, "mysiteShibboleth">

Comment: Are you sure you do not have session management configured in your Application.cfc? If so then session itself is not available. See link For more information about session configuration 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html

Comment: There is a syntax error in the line you just posted. Looking closely at the error CF gives you will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: There is nothing in the application.cfc that indicates about "session management". However, I am able to set and retrieve other sessions variables.

Comment: Thank you for all of you guy's support. It was my stupid mistake. The line <cfif IsDefined("session.mysitecShibboleth.isAuthenticated")>  was working all alone. The line that throws the error was in the <CFELSE> tag that I tried to log the session.mysiteShibboleth.isAuthenticated because this session was not even set; thus, it came to the ELSE statement.